# AngularJS - repeating over an array of IDs, how can I look them up?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Rather vague question, hopefully this will explain better. I'm grabbing the following JSON:

```
{
  items: [
    { name: "item 1", options: [1, 2, 3] }, 
    { name: "item 2", options: [2, 3] }, 
    { name: "item 3", options: [1] }
  ],
  options: [
    { id: 1, color: "red" }, 
    { id: 2, color: "blue" }, 
    { id: 3, color: "yellow" }
  ]
}
```

And I'm repeating over the items like so:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span>{{ name }}</span>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="i in item.options">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to access the color parameter (and others) in my second ng-repeat loop (rather than just the number primitive). What's the best way to do that? Should I do a map on the options array for each item when I'm initializing, and turn each index into the full object (with id and color)? Or can I pass the index to the controller, do a look up and extend my scope with the option I looked up?

Comment: Another repeat, since `options` is outside of `items`

Comment: @Dave If any of the below answers were helpful, please upvote them. If any were correct, please mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li data-ng-repeat="i in item.options">{{options[i-1].color}}</li>
```

Edit: If options array is unsorted:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="i in item.options">{{getColor(i)}}</li>
```

**controller.js**:

```
$scope.getColor = function(i) {
  for(var index=0, len=$scope.options.length; index<len; index++) {
    if ($scope.options.index.id===i) return $scope.options.index.color;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that 'i' is the id of the option and not necessarily a direct relation to the index of it in the options array. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You're right, but if your id is always equal to `index+1`, it doesn't matter. If your `options` array is unsorted, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a function to get the options associated with your item.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RZvH2lWilQaIUJTq4DUL?p=info

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="item in items">
      <span>{{ name }}</span>
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="i in getOptions(item.options)">{{i.color}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { name: "item 1", options: [1, 2, 3] }, 
    { name: "item 2", options: [2, 3] }, 
    { name: "item 3", options: [1] }
  ];
  $scope.options= [
    { id: 1, color: "red" }, 
    { id: 2, color: "blue" }, 
    { id: 3, color: "yellow" }
  ];

  $scope.getOptions = function(options) {
    var rv = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.options, function(option, idx){
       if(options.indexOf(option.id) > -1)
       {
         rv.push(option);
       }
     });
    return rv;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to return the `options` part in your JSON as this structure

```
options: {
    "1": "red", 
    "2": "blue", 
    "3": "yellow"
}
```

Then you can access it by the key since it is a JavaScript object:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="i in item.options">{{options[i]}}</li>
```